# Textfield takes extra space in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-jetpack

When I am trying to put another composable next to TextField, TextField takes extra place.[image]

Red is TextField.
Orange is the composable that should be next to it exactly.

I tried to use `.widthIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity)` on `Modifier`

Also I noticed that TextField has this

```
modifier = modifier
                .defaultMinSize(
                    minWidth = TextFieldDefaults.MinWidth,
                    minHeight = TextFieldDefaults.MinHeight
                )
```

on its `Modifier`,
`val MinWidth = 280.dp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically I used BasicTextField and added                 `.width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` in its `Modifier`

Answer (score 1):

Use `BasicTextField` instead of `TextField`.

`TextField` has some non-customizable properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).